# Between but NOT inclusive with sub query

Tags: mysql, between

I have seen replies to this when using dates but not with sub queries.  I have the following

```
SELECT  *
FROM  `TEST` 
where `ID` BETWEEN
(SELECT `ID`  FROM `TEST` WHERE `Home_Team`
REGEXP 'saturday|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday' 
order by ID asc LIMIT 1)
AND 
(SELECT `ID` FROM `TEST` WHERE `Home_Team`
REGEXP 'saturday|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday' 
order by ID asc LIMIT 1,1)
```

I would like the results not to be inclusive.  unfortunately, im not having any luck with any of  < > =

Answer (score 2):

Best I'm aware, `a BETWEEN b and c` is syntactic sugar for `b <= a and a <= c`, i.e. always inclusive. To make it exclusive, rewrite it as `b < a and a < c`.

Answer (score 0):

Is `ID` an integer? If so, just `+1` and `-1` where appropriate:

```
SELECT  *
FROM  `TEST` 
where `ID` BETWEEN
(SELECT `ID`  FROM `TEST` WHERE `Home_Team`
REGEXP 'saturday|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday' 
order by ID asc LIMIT 1) + 1
AND 
(SELECT `ID` FROM `TEST` WHERE `Home_Team`
REGEXP 'saturday|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday' 
order by ID asc LIMIT 1,1) - 1
```